# Are dashboards/maps created with Python's Bokeh and Folium modules secured? Is the data uploaded to any external server?

Tags: python, bokeh, folium, data-security

The work I do requires some level of security so that only intended parties have access to the data that would be displayed in the dashboards/maps. I just want to make sure Bokeh and Folium are secured choices. So are the HTML files containing the Bokeh dashboards and Folium maps self-contained?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are speaking about standalone Bokeh content, e.g. created with `output_file` and `show` or embedded in web pages with `components` or `json_items`, and not speaking about Bokeh server applications.

In that case, all data for the Bokeh data sources, etc. resides purely in the HTML page that is loaded by the browser. Depending on how you configure BokehJS resources, the page may load the BokehJS runtime externally from the Bokeh CDN at `cdn.bokeh.org`. This is the default configuration. If you prefer, it is possible to create completely self-contained HTML that includes the BokehJS scripts directly in the page. One way to do that is to specify the environment variable `BOKEH_RESOURCES=inline`.

It should probably go without saying that whatever Python process of yours generates the Bokeh content also necessarily has access to the data, but securing that would be your responsibility. Also, of course, limiting the distribution or access to the resulting generated HTML is also your responsibility.

Folium is a completely separate question that can't comment on. Presumably it will always need to call out to some remote service to load the map tiles, at least.